# Screenshot video stops after two seconds on fresh install of 22.04

Tags: video, screenshot, capture

When I start the screenshot functionality (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), choose the video and then hit the red record button, I can see that the screen capture is being started as the video counter is running at the top right screen. But after two seconds it automatically stops and no video is captured. I tried another laptop with Ubuntu and got the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 yesterday and there are no dependency issues.